# MAGENTO 2.4 WHEN EXPORT BY BULK 10, 100 AND 1000 PRODUCTS ITS OK BUT I CAN NOT WITH 4000

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am newbye with Magento.... the issue i am experienced at this moment is when i try to export 10, 100 or 1000 products everything goes ok and the CSV file appears to be downloaded properly.... but when i tried to get 4000 products it never appears...

what i can see is the file csv in path var/ the file with 0 bytes.

please help... i think is a limitation but i do not know what to do...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you check max_execution_time in php.ini? and increase it to see if it has some effect?

Comment: how long does it suppose has to be..???